# JPanels: One with a JTextArea and another with a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

I've been at this for a good while now, but I cannot seem to get a hand of it. I'm trying to produce a JPanel that has a JTextArea above and two JLabels below, but my JLabel ends up on the left side of my JTextArea and I cannot make the other appear.

Here's my code (sorry for the display stuff- just filler really):

```
public JPanel contentPane() {
    JPanel something = new JPanel();

    String information = "Please";

    info = new JTextArea(information, 4, 30);
    info.setEditable(false);
    info.setLineWrap(true);
    info.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JPanel one = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    one.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    one.setLocation(10, 10);
    one.setSize(50, 50);
    one.add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    something.add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel two = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    two.setBackground(null);
    two.setLocation(220, 10);
    two.setSize(50, 50);
    two.add(new JLabel("Please work"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    two.add(new JLabel("Oh gosh, please"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    something.add(two, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    something.setOpaque(true);
    return something;
}

public static void GUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("You Guessed It!");

    DisplayStudent panel = new DisplayStudent();
    frame.setContentPane(panel.contentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Please and thank you to anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @masterX244  7.4 I believe.

Answer (score 6):

When you create you *something*, you don't specify any layout manager, but later on you attempt to add *one* to *something* using BorderLayout constants -- which will not work, since the default layout manager for a JPanel is FlowLayout.

Try this instead;

```
JPanel something = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a GridLayout() which will let you lay any elements out in a grid: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: GridLayout is nice as long as you want to have all components in the panel with exactly the same size. When you start to mix sizes and want to have different dynamics (e.g., some might scale horizontally, others vertically, anchored NORTH, some should stretch, etc etc...) you ned to change to GridBagLayout which is by far the most "generic" layout manager I'm using.

Comment: @Markus Millfjord  It worked, but now my JLabels appear in the center instead on the east and west respectfully. What else am I missing?

Comment: Well, BorderLayout is not perhaps the best choice here, since it will only show the components that are actually added. And, the different places (NORTH, CENTER, SOUTH, etc) all treat their components differently; CENTER components are stretched horizontally and vertically, whereas NORTH and SOUTH are stretched horizontally only. In your case, you have your labels in *two*, and you've tried to set it's size to (50,50), and placed *two* in the *something's* SOUTH. To force the labels to EAST and WEST, you need to add a dummy-component to the CENTER in *two*, and play with two's setSize

Comment: Furthermore, you shouldn't try to setLocation at all, if you're using layout managers. So, if you want a quick-n-dirty approach of just showing your components in the way you specify (since you use setLocation and setSize), you could just set the *something*'s layout manager to null instead, allowing you to place manually on pixel-level. I personally don't like to NOT use a layout manager, but I guess it all comes down to what you want to do and how dynamic the end application needs to be.

Comment: @Markus Millfjord  It works now! Thank you so much for all of your help, friend. I appreciate it from the bottom of my heart.